# ASp.net core tool not installing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[I am installing asp.net core tools but it is continuously giving this error shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnHEa.png)

**Error 0x80070490**: Process returned error: 0x490 Error 0x80070490:

Failed to execute EXE package. Error 0x80070490:
Failed to configure per-machine EXE package. Applied execute package: DotNetCLI_x64, result: 0x80070490, restart: None Error 0x80070490:
Failed to execute EXE package. Removing cached package: DotNetCLI_x64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\8B4ACC662D4A8759AB418CA5F92FE4721D21B190

Comment: open image by clicking image description

Comment: and what log says ?

Comment: there are many characters more than 8000 how I write

Comment: Error 0x80070490: Process returned error: 0x490
Error 0x80070490: Failed to execute EXE package.
Error 0x80070490: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
Applied execute package: DotNetCLI_x64, result: 0x80070490, restart: None
Error 0x80070490: Failed to execute EXE package.
Removing cached package: DotNetCLI_x64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\8B4ACC662D4A8759AB418CA5F92FE4721D21B190\

Comment: You should include the test of the error in your question. This makes it easier for others to search when they have similar errors. An image is fine, but only as supplementary to the post.

Comment: I did not understand what do you mean by test. I am installing the tools not testing anything. so how can I test while instaling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [vc_redist](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840), then install asp.net core.

Take a look in this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/4190) for more information.